# CSS Margins iPad

Tags: html, ios, css, ipad

This might be a simple question, but I can't seem to figure it out.  I'm trying to set the margins on my site so that there is a small gap b/w the containers and the edges of the iPad screen.  This should explain what I mean:

On this site: http://www.thesandiegocriminallawyer.com/ - there is small gap b/w the content and edge of iPad (left and right side).

On this site:  http://www.legalindustrymarketing.com/ - there is NO space b/w content and iPad edge of screen.

I tried using the same CSS code that seems to control it (see below), but no effect.  What CSS do I need to create a small gap between left/right edges of content and edge of iPad screen?

Thanks.

CSS (from [www.thesandiegocriminallawyer.com](http://www.thesandiegocriminallawyer.com))

```
 #header-wrap, #banner-wrap, #nav-wrap, #main-wrap, #footer-wrap {
        min-width: 940px;
        width: 100%; }
```

Comment: Are you talking about a margin on the left and right side of the content area? To give some padding? Or the top and bottom? I'm not seeing that on either site when I resize to iPad size...

Comment: Yes, on the left and right side.  Just a small amount of space.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm trying to control the width so the content is not squished against the side I just do this for the wrap;

```
.wrap {
width: 90%
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: thank you.  So just put the whole thing in a wrap and change the width slightly?  Ok, I'll try that.  Thank you.

Comment: that's what I do for mobile development.  It seems to look nice on android and ios.